# Javascript Three-Level Combination

Tags: javascript, combinations

I'm trying to create a little JavaScript tool where I can create the combinations out of three lists. Each combination consists of one consonant, one niqqudot, and one teamim. I thought it could be solved with simple nested loops, but the "document.write" line results in an infinite loop and it does not seem to increment. The first combination is repeated over and over, but it never goes to the next combination. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could take a look at the code and see why that might be. Thanks!

```
function combine()
{
    // lists
    var consonants = ["&#x05D0;", "&#x05D1;", "&#x05D2;", "&#x05D3;", "&#x05D4;", "&#x05D5;", "&#x05D6;", "&#x05D7;", "&#x05D8;", "&#x05D9;", "&#x05DA;", "&#x05DB;", "&#x05DC;", "&#x05DD;", "&#x05DE;", "&#x05DF;", "&#x05E0;", "&#x05E1;", "&#x05E2;", "&#x05E3;", "&#x05E4;", "&#x05E5;", "&#x05E6;", "&#x05E7;", "&#x05E8;", "&#x05E9;&#x05C1;", "&#x05E9;&#x05C2;", "&#x05EA;"];

    var niqqudot = ["", "&#x05B0;", "&#x05B1;", "&#x05B2;", "&#x05B3;", "&#x05B4;", "&#x05B5;", "&#x05B6;", "&#x05B7;", "&#x05B8;", "&#x05B9;", "&#x05BB;", "&#x05C7;", "&#x05BF;", "&#x05C4;", "&#x05C5;", "&#x05BC;", "&#x05BD;"];

    var teamim = ["", "&#x0591;", "&#x0592;", "&#x0593;", "&#x0594;", "&#x0595;", "&#x0596;", "&#x0597;", "&#x0598;", "&#x0599;", "&#x059A;", "&#x059B;", "&#x059C;", "&#x059D;", "&#x059E;", "&#x059F;", "&#x05A0;", "&#x05A1;", "&#x05A2;", "&#x05A3;", "&#x05A4;", "&#x05A5;", "&#x05A6;", "&#x05A7;", "&#x05A8;", "&#x05A9;", "&#x05AA;", "&#x05AB;", "&#x05AC;", "&#x05AD;", "&#x05AE;", "&#x05AF;"];

    // all combinations
    var combinations = "";

    // counter variables
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    var k = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < consonants.length; i+1)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < niqqudot.length; j+1)
        {
            for (k = 0; k < teamim.length; k+1)
            {
                //combinations = combinations + consonants[i] + niqqudot[j] + teamim[k]+ "\r\n" ;
                document.write(consonants[i] + niqqudot[j] + teamim[k] + "\r\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expressions

> i+1
>   j+1
>   k+1

don't alter the values of the counting variables themselves. They simply evaluate, and have no side effects. You need to say i+=1, j+=1, k+=1. Otherwise, how would the interpreter know what variable to assign the value to?

Comment: *"You need to say i+=1, j+=1, k+=1."* That's not correct. There are other options, so you don't *"need"* to use that form. Why are you trying to confuse the asker with misleading information? *(Note that I didn't down-vote you. I've no need to promote my answer by voting others down.)*

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
i+1
j+1
k+1
```

do:

```
i++
j++
k++
```

or:

```
i=i+1
j=j+1
k=k+1
```

Comment: Because while it may seem obvious to you and I, you didn't explain to the person asking the question WHY this is correct.

Comment: @Greg: Well that's just silly. The code is entirely self-explanatory. I mean `i+1` doesn't work, but change it to `i++` and it suddenly works. It doesn't take a rocket scientist to figure out that one modifies and the other doesn't.

Comment: If it was that obvious to everyone, would he be asking the question?

Comment: @Greg: You're joking right? It wasn't obvious *before he was given the solution*. It is obvious once the solution has been presented.

Comment: I don't know whether it was obvious to him or not, seeing as I'm not him! I do know however it is good form to explain an answer.

Comment: @Greg: Oh, considering the code that OP has managed to write so far... oh, never mind. I've answered 2,400 questions before this one, I certainly don't need to justify anything to you.

Comment: No you don't need to justify anything...you asked why the -1 and I told you. If you don't agree, well its only -2 and you clearly have enough answers that it shouldn't make a difference to you.

Comment: Thank you to Greg for the explanation and thank you to @patrick-dw for showing me that there are other options - I greatly appreciate it!